# Can I rely on openssl_random_pseudo_bytes() being very random in PHP?

Tags: php, openssl, random

I came across an application which needs to generate a random token for each user. It is very important that each generated token is unique. Application code was as follows:

```
$token = md5(open_ssl_random_pseudo_bytes(64));
```

I don't know exactly how `open_ssl_random_pseudo_bytes` works or why the  number "64" was chosen, nor how those bytes play together with MD5 hashing.

So how random is this token really? If the code is ran 1 billion times, will the tokens be unique?

Comment: `If the code is ran 1 billion times, will the tokens be unique?` For this something like 8 bytes would be more then enough, IF `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes` works correctly on your system.

Comment: No, you should not really rely on OpenSSL here [#1](https://externals.io/message/103345) [#2](https://github.com/paragonie/random_compat/issues/96) [#3](https://github.com/paragonie/random_compat/issues/5). As soon as you’re on PHP 7.0+, there’s really no excuse anymore to use it. From that version on, *always* prefer the built-in `random_bytes` function.

Comment: There is no way to ensure uniqueness of random or pseudorandom numbers, by definition, no matter how they are obtained. If you are generating a unique identifier, ensure it is unique the way Microsoft GUIDs are unique: have one component be a location, another be a time. Or else maintain a hash table of all generated IDs so you can detect duplicates.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

open_ssl_random_pseudo_bytes is a [cryptographically secure pseudo random number generator (CSPRNG)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographically_secure_pseudorandom_number_generator).

In layman's terms, this means that it can generate an unpredictable, uniformly distributed sequence, that is suitable for key generation. The unpredictable property is important, because even if the full state of the random number generator is known, an attacker cannot recreate previously generated sequences, and it is unfeasible for an external observer to guess the state in order to predict future sequences.

This is in contrast to say a random number generator that takes its seed from the number of seconds past midnight and then generates predictable sequences based on this seed. In this case an attacker can simply set their own system to generate numbers using the same seed and can effectively guess token values in order to use them for their own nefarious purposes.

64 bytes will give you 512 bits of entropy. Since MD5 outputs hashes of 128 bits, there is no advantage of having the entropy generated being greater than 128. If the code is ran one billion times then there is a statistically probable chance of it always being unique because you have an output keyspace of 2<sup>128</sup> (3.4 * 10<sup>38</sup>). The [collision rate of MD5 is about 2<sup>64</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8852731/413180) which is about 18 billion billion.

Comment: Let's say the system uses number that gives more than 128 bits (64 for example), how does it affect collision rate? Is there a greater or smaller probability then? Or it simply doesn't matter?

Comment: For all practical purposes I'd say it doesn't matter - you're still getting a 128 bit hash output - the chances of an accidental clash (even with MD5) on input greater than 128 bits are improbable, even though the collision resistance property of MD5 is broken. The code above looks like it is only generating an MD5 so it has a fixed length string to work with. It could simply do this with the [`bin2hex`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.bin2hex.php) function over 16 bytes in order to remove the need for hashing completely.

Comment: To be exact, CSPRNG only guarantees that previous output cannot be reconstructed even if current state is known. If you know full state of any CSPRNG you can predict all future output unless that CSRPNG has additional entropy input. And in that case, the quality of output is strictly limited by quality of entropy input. Initial state / seeding or real entropy input are crusial for all CSRPNG implementations. "Random Number Generation Is Too Important to Be Left to Chance".

Comment: @MikkoRantalainen: Thanks for pointing that out. Updated.

Answer (score 7):

You should be aware of [PHP bug #70014](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=70014) which was pretty recent and affects the reliability of `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes()`.

I've been working on [paragonie/random_compat](https://github.com/paragonie/random_compat), which backports `random_bytes()` from PHP 7 into PHP 5. One of the fallbacks it supports is `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes()`, but if it can read directly from `/dev/urandom` it will prefer that instead.

Comment: Note that Windows does not have the /dev/urandom mechanism.

Comment: Creating a file in `C:\dev\random` can break some naive PHP code. :)

Answer (score 1):

There's another bug with openssl_random_pseudo_bytes ([71915](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=71915)), which can result in duplicate values when you run it multiple times with the same process ID. Looks like it's fixed in 5.6.24.

Answer (score 1):

It's better to use [random_bytes](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.random-bytes.php) than openssl_random_pseudo_bytes.

From the manual(available since php 7.x) :

```
random_bytes — Generates cryptographically secure pseudo-random bytes
```

Sample code (from the manual too):

```
 <?php

   $bytes = random_bytes(5);
   var_dump(bin2hex($bytes));

 ?>
```

Comment: Why is it better?

Comment: Cryptographically secure out of the box, cross platform and throws an exception when an appropriate source of randomness  is not available

Comment: Are you saying that openssl_random_pseudo_bytes() doesn't do that? I was rather under the impression it did.

Comment: @symcbean It doesn't throw an exception. That second optional parameter of the openssl function looks a little worrying, as well. (Since it sounds like it's something that would need to be checked, but most people won't do this or know to do this.) The strongest benefit might be that it doesn't force a dependency on openssl. Some people use alternative TLS implementations. And for good reasons. Finally, the PHP function will even work on systems without HTTPS support.

Comment: @symcbean And also, OpenSSL (I believe) still insists on using a custom userspace implementation of an entropy-collecting RNG. That's always a red flag. Exploitable bugs tend to surface in those types of implementations. And often...